# How did Thor in Infinity War know that the Time Stone was with the Avengers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones, avengers-infinity-war

In *Infinity War*, Thor tells the Guardians of the Galaxy that

> the Time and Mind Stones are safe on earth, they’re with the Avengers.

The Mind Stone is OK (it’s part of Vision, after the events of *Age of Ultron*), but the Time Stone was with Dr. Strange and he was not part of the Avengers. In fact, nobody from the Avengers knew about the Time Stone.

Comment: Strange is wearing the amulet when he talks to Thor in Ragnarok, so maybe he sensed it?

Comment: Technically speaking, at the start of *Infinity War*, Vision isn't part of the Avengers either. He and Scarlet Witch are fugitives following the events of Civil War.

Comment: Was Strange wearing it when talking to Thor in the mid credits sequence of Dr Strange [2016]? Or were they talking in near enough proximity for him to know it was there?

Comment: Perhaps by 'safe on Earth with the Avengers' he meant that the stones were on Earth, and thus safe because the Avengers were around to defend them? As in, the Avengers didn't have the stones, but would stop Thanos from coming through and stealing them?

Comment: Don't forget that Thanos' minions also went directly to Vision in Scotland to take his stone.  They knew where he was when Stark did not (locators were turned off).  So they seem to have some way of detecting the exact location of the stones. It wasnt shown how they did this.

Comment: Didn't Thor bathed in the *Water of Sights* in *Age of Ultron*?

Answer (score 16):

Thanos told his minions to find the two stones that are on Earth just after he kills Loki and before he uses the Power and Space stones to blow up the Asgardian ship and escape (respectively). Thor already knew the location of 4 of them: he knew the Space and Power stones were with Thanos, he knew the Mind stone was on Earth, and he knew the Reality stone was with the Collector. He states when talking to the Guardians that nobody has ever seen or knows where the Soul stone is, so by process of elimination the other stone that Thanos said is on Earth must be the Time stone. That doesn't necessarily mean that he knew who on Earth actually had it though.

It is possible that Heimdall knew that Dr. Strange had the Time stone and told Thor at some point prior to his death. When he wants, Heimdall can see anyone in the nine realms.

Comment: Except Thor specifically says that the time and mind stones are 'with the Avengers'.  Process of elimination doesn't tell him that.

Comment: I already added that caveat - read the final sentence of the first paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 6):

When Thor says those two stones are safe on earth, and with the Avengers, he may just mean that they’re on the same planet as the Avengers, and will thus be protected by them (even if they don’t currently possess the Time Stone).

It’s also worth remembering that Thor is King of Asgard — in his mind, earth is probably somewhere he occasionally goes, and the Avengers are lucky people who get the honour of fighting with him when he does. He may have assumed Strange, who he met in *Thor: Ragnarok*, was part of the Avengers because he’s from earth and has powers - he’s King of Asgard, he’s not checking the membership rosters personally. (As his “he hasn’t fought me!” comment about Thanos a little later suggests, he’s not really a details guy.)

Comment: Hi Paul. When Gamora asks Thor , where Thanos might go next , Thor says he is going to Nowhere. He explains , Thanos took Power stone when he decimated Xandar , took Power stone from him killing Loki , and then he says  Mind and Time stone are safe on Earth , Nobody knows about Soul stone  where it is , therefore he is going to Nowhere to collect Reality stone from the collector .

Comment: @AmbernathI: “ then he says Mind and Time stone are safe on Earth” — right, but like you said in your question, he also mentions the Avengers.

Comment: Would be worth watching their meeting again; I'm pretty sure the entire thing was onscreen.  Some of, if not all of, the scene cuts weren't movie magic but Strange teleporting them around.  Thor gets woozy from it at one point.

Comment: @Izkata: yup, having re-watched, it definitely plays as if we’re seeing the whole encounters and there’s no discussion of Infinity Stones.

Answer (score 5):

In the beginning of Thor: Ragnarok, Thor said he was actually looking for Infinity Stones. In his research, he migt have heard of the Eye of Agamotto and more precisly what is inside the amulet.

Even if he looks surprised by the presence of wizard on Earth, it could explain why he knows that the Time Stone was near the Avengers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This is a nice first answer but it would be improved if you could add the relevant quotes to your answer!

Comment: From [the film's transcript](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Thor:_Ragnarok): "See, I spent some time on Earth... Fought some robots, saved the planet a couple of times. Then I went searching through the Cosmos for some magic, colorful Infinity Stone things."